# Why can't TextDocumentContentProvider be used with openTextDocument

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

From the docs for `openTextDocument`:

> Two schemes are supported:
>
> file: A file on disk, will be rejected if the file does not exist or
>   cannot be loaded, e.g. file:///Users/frodo/r.ini.
>
> untitled: A new file
>   that should be saved on disk, e.g. untitled:c:\frodo\new.js. The
>   language will be derived from the file name.
>
> **Uris with other schemes will make this method return a rejected
>   promise.**

If you attempt to use `openTextDocument`, passing a Uri that corresponds to your registered `TextDocumentContentProvider`, the provider is called, you return some text (or a `Thenable<string>`) and then the Promise fails because the uri scheme is not `file://` or `untitled://`.

This seems utterly absurd behaviour - why not just use the text given by the provider to create the document?

Comment: That behaviour seems weird indeed. But I don't think this is the right place to discuss this question. I'd rather open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to add it - but there are comments on GitHub that questions should be asked on SO, rather than raising an issue. Maybe I picked the wrong choice :-)